# How do I rename a gemset?

Tags: ruby, rvm

Is there an RVM command to simply rename a gemset?  I couldn't find it on the RVM site.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

There is an RVM gemset rename command. I'm not sure when it was introduced but it is present in 1.0.16.

```
rvm gemset rename current_gemset_name new_gemset_name
```

As of RVM 1.21 or higher it will automatically switch you to the newly renamed gemset.

If you are on an older version of RVM you'll also need to switch to the newly created gemset, as follows:

```
rvm gemset use new_gemset_name
```

Running the command `rvm gemset list` will tell you the current gemset you are operating within.

Comment: This gives me `ERROR: 'current_gemset_name' does not exist`. **rvm 1.8.6**

Comment: on my mac, it also gives me ERROR: 'current_gemset_name' does not exist

Comment: This should not be fixed in the latest version. To update rvm type: `rvm get latest`

Comment: Latest version RVM now switches to the newly renamed gemset (1.21.20).

Answer (score 10):

I copied one with

```
rvm gemset copy <gemset_from> <gemset_dest>
```

and then deleted the previous one with

```
rvm gemset delete <gemset_from>
```

Comment: Hmmm ... I did that and the gems didn't show up in the new gemset.  The command line feedback I did this:
`rvm gemset copy demo2 rails_admin`  Then it said:
Copying gemset from demo2 to rails_admin (and)
Making gemset for rails_admin pristine.

I'm not sure what that last sentence is about.  I have rvm version 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

It's a RVM bug!

Solved in this pull request: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/592#issuecomment-2705466
Commit: https://github.com/jwhitley/rvm/commit/619e5265927cf6c842ec3561345569af474ed20e

Comment: Cool ... I had been on rvm 1.9.3, then I did `rvm get head` (see for example http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/upgrading/ ), and now the rename command works properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error that your gemset doesn't exist, but it exist you have to chose appropriate ruby version!

For example, if you have gemset ree@something-x and you current rvm (rvm current) is ruby-1.9.3-p194 then you have to execute

```
rvm use ree
```

and then

```
rvm gemset rename something-x something-y
```

It works with rvm version 1.16.17